# How to program a dialog box in GUI, Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a dialog box in Matlab (GUI) with "Ok" button.

h = msgbox('Please press Ok to display the image')

Then I used imshow to display that image:

imshow('myImage.jpg')

I want the GUI wait for the user's response (pressing OK) and then show the image but now these two happens at the same time. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `uiwait` and set message dialog box to be `modal` before `imshow`:

```
uiwait(msgbox('Please press Ok to display the image','Test msg box','modal'));
```

or:

```
h = msgbox('Please press Ok to display the image','Test msg box','modal');
uiwait(h);
```